# Pass var value from HTML to python

Tags: python, html, forms

Im using python3 and i have this HTMl which create buttons that it gets from a python list :

```
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
{% for thing in value %}
<form method="get" action="/loader" value="submit">
  <button class="button button">{{ thing }}</button>
</form>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

my python code:

```
@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def test():
    a = ["a1","a2"]
    return render_template('sbutton.html', value=a)

@app.route("/loader", methods=["GET"])
def loader():
    data = request.args.get()
    print(data)
    return render_template('loader.html', value=password)
```

So i will see buttons a1 and a2 in the website `http://localhost/test` 
And when i press one of them i will redirect to `/loader` which is a route in my python code to another html.

I want that when i press a button, for example `a1`, i will get this information back to my python
inside the `loader` function.

i tried `<form method="get" action="/loader" value="submit">` 
Added the `value="submit` but i dont get anything under `print(data)`

I just need to know on which button client clicked  when he is redirected to `/loader` in my code.
I want to keep this value as a var in my python.

Thanks

Comment: you can check that here. may be this could help you
[click here ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057621/django-pass-variable-into-template/53059318)

Comment: no, he is trying to do the opposite, and i dont want to use django but thanks. im sure my HTML is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`data = request.args.get()` should be called on the exact parameter you want to fetch, e.g. `get('username')`. Examples are [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_http_methods.htm). As an aside, the data is passed from `HTTP`, the protocol that the values are transported through, not HTML, the markup language. If you want all values, `request.args` will return a dictionary with key-value pairs of all GET parameters passed.

Comment: if i do `request.args` ill get :`  ImmutableMultiDict([])` , im sending it the wrong way i think

Comment: You have to use something else to fetch the items from the dict. I believe `request.args.items()` might work here

Comment: Thanks fot the help, now i get `<generator object MultiDict.items at 0x7fcffb3d9eb8>`

Comment: https://tedboy.github.io/flask/generated/generated/werkzeug.ImmutableMultiDict.html Look into the docs here to work out how to retrieve it in a format you can use

Comment: Its somthing to do with my HTMl , i get empty response.

Comment: Your `button` objects don't have names so they can't pass their values. Also, I'd recommend your for loop to go inside your form, so you have one for all buttons, rather than each button having its own form.

Comment: They have a name, its one name from the list `['a1', 'a1']`, i made `form` inside the loop, stil same result

Comment: The buttons do not have a name attribute, so do not pass to GET

Comment: I thought I’d explain why it wasn’t working, for future reference. I’m also not sure why you’re adding a hidden input, instead of just adding the name to the button and putting it all in one form

Comment: I still dont understand what do you mean by "it has no name" if you could write an exsample to a button with name? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, i was able to catch the button value name like this :

```
{% for thing in value %}
  <form method="get" action="/loader">
    <input type=hidden name="{{ thing }}">
    <button class="button button">{{ thing }}</button>
  </form>
{% endfor %}
```

And my code it redirects to :

```
@app.route("/loader", methods=["GET"])
def loader():
    data = dict(request.args)
    for key in data:
        print(key)
    return render_template('loader.html', value=password)
```

So now after i click the button i get the value back to my python /loader function
If client press on a1 button ill get a1 in python.