# Django input not showing

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

Im building a site using Django. I am trying to pass an input from `index.html` and display it in `about.html` using `view.py`. 
My input seems to get passed as it is in the url at the top the browser.I am trying to store this value in a variable and display the variable in a html paragraph. However it does not show. Instead of seeing the input associated with the variable i just see the string of text with the variable name.

My `index.html`:

```
<form action="{% url 'theaboutpage' %}">
<input type="text" name="user_input">
<input type="submit" value="click here now">
</form>
```

My `about.html`:

```
<a href={% url 'thehomepage' %}>go back to the home page</a>
<p>{{'input_from_home_page'}}</p>
```

My `views.py`:

```
def about(request):
Hellothere = request.GET['user_input']
return render(request, 'about.html', {'input_from_home_page':Hellothere})
```

Comment: Refer this discussion for more details - [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53057621/django-pass-variable-into-template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the quotation marks around the variable in your template at `about.html`. It should look like this:

```
<p>{{ input_from_home_page }}</p>
```

As side notes:

1. If the information entered in `<input type="text" name="user_input">` is sensitive information, then you should consider passing it using "POST" HTTP method instead of "GET". In which case, remember to include the [`{% csrf_token %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/). To get the passed info, you can use: `request.POST.get('user_input')` in your view.
2. By [convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names), you should name variables with lowercase. In your case, it's nice to have `hello_there` instead of `Hellothere`.